# Basis of a subspace starting from a given subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I was given the following subspaces:
$$E=\mathrm{Span}\{(1,0,1), (2,0,-1),(1,0,0)\}\\F=\mathrm{Span}\{(1,0,2),(1,1,1),(1,-1,3)\}$$
I found that a basis for $E\cap F$ is $\{(\frac{1}{2},0,1)\}$. Now, I am asked to expand this basis to get a basis for $E$, $F$ and $E+F$. I do not know how to proceed know, can somebody help me?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. $E$ and $F$ are not subspaces as they are put forward here. Do you mean that $E = \text{Span} \{ ... \}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is exactly what I meant,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe that $\text{dim}(E)=\text{dim}(F)=2$, and
$$E=\langle(1,0,1),(2,0,-1)\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle \text{ and }F=\langle(1,0,2),(1,1,1)\rangle=\langle s,t \rangle$$ (with gaussian elimination you find that the matrices whose columns are the vectors that span $E$ and $F$ have two non-zero pivot, so their dimension is two).

We want now to find a basis for $E\cap F$: imposing $\alpha u+\beta v=\gamma t+\delta s$ and solving the matrix associated to the system $\alpha u+\beta v-\gamma t-\delta v=0$, we obtain $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=(-5t,t,-3t,0)$, $t\in\mathbb R$.
One possible vector that span $E\cap F$ is $(1,0,2)$.

We know that $\text{dim}(E)+\text{dim}(F)-\text{dim}(E\cap F)=\text{dim}(E+F)=3=\text{dim}(\mathbb R^3)$.
To extend the basis of the intersection to $E$, $F$ and $E+F$ we only have to add vectors linearly independent with $(1,0,2)$. For example, we can generate $E+F$ with $(1,0,2),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and we can easily add the vector $u$ and $t$ to generate respectively $E$ and $F$.

Rmk: If $W$ is a vector subspace of dimension $k$ and $w_1,\dots,w_k$ are linearly independent, than $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ is a basis for $W$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful!

Comment: Sure! And again, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad my answer helped you :-)